# error: no known conversion from 'foo1*' to 'const foo2&'

Tags: c++, polymorphism, constants, copy-constructor

May i know what to do to the parameter `a` in `main()` so that i can call the copy constructor?

```
class foo1 {
public:
    virtual void display() = 0;
};

class foo2 : public foo1
{
public:
    foo2();
    foo2(const foo2& a);
    void display()
    {
        cout << "Copy constructor works\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo1* a = new foo2;
    foo1* b = new foo2(a);
}
```

thanks if anyone could help

Comment: i've tried, but i faced another error: no known conversion from 'foo1' to 'const foo2&'

Comment: downcasts need to be explicit - try `*dynamic_cast<foo2*>(a)`, here's the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)

Comment: @UnholySheep it doesn't work, error : `undefined reference to `foo2::foo2(foo2 const&)` . My code is like this `foo1* b = new foo2(*dynamic_cast<foo2*>(a));` , correct me if i typed wrongly

Comment: No, that is correct - it compiles, but you get a linker error, because you haven't actually defined a copy constructor - you only declared it. You need to actually write a definition for it in order to link as well

Comment: @UnholySheep i got it, thanks for your help!!

Comment: One last note: `*dynamic_cast<foo2*>(a)` is unsafe - you should always first check if the cast actually succeeded. So you should in reality do something along the lines of: `foo2* tmp = dynamic_cast<foo2*>(a); if(tmp) { b = new foo2(*tmp); }`

Comment: alright, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your copy constructor needs reference (address ) and you trying to pass a pointer. so ether you want to create actual object and not a pointer or deference pointer